# Show that if $\phi \oplus \psi \leq c \implies \inf_{\gamma \geq 0} \int c - \phi \oplus \psi d\gamma = 0 $

Tags: optimization, supremum-and-infimum, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, optimal-transport

In the book Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians, the original problem for Optimal Transport is written as:
$$
\min_\gamma \quad \int_{X \times Y} c d\gamma \quad + \quad
\sup_{\phi,\psi} \quad \int_X \phi d\mu + \int_Y \psi d\nu - \int_{X \times Y}\phi(x) - \psi(y) d\gamma
$$

Where $\gamma \in \mathcal P(X\times Y)$ and $\mu,\nu \in \mathcal P(X),\mathcal P(Y)$, respectively.

Then, the author writes the dual as:

$$
\sup_{\phi,\psi} \quad \int_X \phi d\mu +  \int_Y \psi d\nu  \quad +
 \quad \inf_\gamma \quad \int_{X \times Y} c(x,y) - \phi(x) - \psi(y) d\gamma
$$

Finally, the author then claims the following:
$$
\inf_\gamma \quad \int_{X \times Y} c(x,y) - \phi(x) - \psi(y) d\gamma = 0, \quad 
 = \begin{cases}
  0, & \text{if } \phi \oplus  \psi \leq c \quad \text{on }X\times Y \\
  -\infty, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} 
$$

My question is why if $\phi \oplus \psi \leq c \implies \inf_{\gamma \geq 0} \int c - \phi \oplus \psi d\gamma = 0 $ ?

Since $\gamma $ is a probability measure, is not like I can make the measure as small as I'd like.

For the case where $\gamma$ is just a positive measure, then I can see how we could make $\gamma=0$. But I don’t see how this would be valid assuming that we are dealing with probability measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the book you can see that the infimum is taken over $\mathscr{M}_+(X\times Y)$ - meaning the space of positive finite measures.
Therefore you can just choose $\gamma$ to be the zero measure.